# Expectation of Truncated distribution with two random variables in conditional

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> How to find the conditional expectation $$\mathbb E[A_1\mid A_1\ge A_m,A_2 \ge A_m,A_1+A_2 \ge 2A_y]$$ where 
>   \begin{align}
> 0 &\le A_1 \le 1,\\ 0 &\le A_2 \le 1,\\ \frac{1}{2} &< A_m < A_y < 1,
> \end{align} and $A_m, A_y$ are constants. Further, $$\frac{1+A_m}{2}< A_y.$$

If we draw the integration region by using the information in conditional part and the additional ones and keeping $A_1$ in x-axis; $A_2$ in y-axis we get a triangle $ABC$ where the 
coordinates are as follows:

- $A= (2A_y-1,1)$
- $B= (1,1)$
- $C=(1,2A_y-1)$

with $AB$ parallel to $x$-axis, 
$BC$ parallel to $y$-axis, and $AC$ is a diagonal line.

To find the conditional expectation in first line we need to do the following integration:
$$\int A_1 f(A_1\mid A_1\ge A_m,A_2 \ge A_m,A_1+A_2 \ge 2A_y)\mathsf  dA_1.$$

My doubt is what will be the limits of this integration and what will be the conditional density:
$$f(A_1\mid A_1\ge A_m,A_2 \ge A_m,A_1+A_2 \ge 2A_y) \;\text{ ?} $$

Comment: What is the distribution of $(A_1,A_2)$? Are $A_1$ and $A_2$ independent?

Comment: $A_1, A_2$ are independent. First I would like to analyse with both $A_1$, $A_2$ being standard uniform.

Answer (score 1):

Let us use $X$, $Y$, $x$ and $y$ to denote $A_1$, $A_2$, $A_m$ and $A_y$ respectively, then the goal is to compute the ratio $u/v$, where
$$
u=E(X;X\gt x,Y\gt x,X+Y\gt2y),\qquad v=P(X\gt x,Y\gt x,X+Y\gt2y),
$$
where the random variables $X$ and $Y$ are i.i.d. uniform on $(0,1)$, and the real numbers $x$ and $y$ are such that $1\lt2x\lt2y\lt2$ and $2y\gt x+1$.

Note first that if $X+Y\gt2y$ then $1+Y\gt2y\gt x+1$ and $X+1\gt2y\gt x+1$ hence $X\gt x$ and $Y\gt x$. Thus, the conditions that $X\gt x$ and $Y\gt x$ are not useful, and
$$
u=E(X;X+Y\gt2y),\qquad v=P(X+Y\gt2y),
$$
Since $2y\gt1$, one is interested in the density of $Z=X+Y$ on $(1,2)$, which is $z\mapsto2-z$. This yields
$$
v=P(Z\gt2y)=\int_{2y}^2(2-z)\mathrm dz=2(1-y)^2.
$$
To compute $u$, note that $u=E(Y;X+Y\gt2y)$ by symmetry, hence
$$
2u=E(Z;Z\gt2y)=\int_{2y}^2z(2-z)\mathrm dz=\tfrac43(1-y)^2(1+2y).
$$
Finally,
$$
E(X\mid X\gt x,Y\gt x,X+Y\gt2y)=E(X\mid X+Y\gt2y)=\tfrac13(1+2y).
$$

Comment: Thanks for your response. I had a follow up question. I will use same notation defined by you. Say now I want to find $E[X|X < x, Y < x, X+Y < 2y]$. As before X,Y are i.i.d standard uniform random variables. We have from given information that $X+Y < 2x < 2y$, since $x < y$. So $X+Y < 2y$ is redundant information. Hence,$E[X|X < x, Y < x, X+Y < 2y] = E[X|X < x, Y < x]= E[X|X<x]$. The last equality follows because $X$ and $Y$ are independent. $E[X|X<x]=\frac{\int_0^x X dX}{\int_0^x dX }= \frac{x}{2}$. So we get, $E[X|X < x, Y < x, X+Y < 2y]= \frac{x}{2}$. Is this correct ?

Comment: If $X$ has density $f$ and $X\gt0$ almost surely then $E[X\mid X\lt x]=a/b$ with $a=\int\limits_0^xtf(t)\mathrm dt$ and $b=\int\limits_0^xf(t)\mathrm dt$.

Comment: Sorry I was editing. Now I have posted the question.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Just wanted to check out if the logic that I was following for writing $E[X|X < x, Y < x, X+Y < 2y] = E[X| X < x]$ correct or not ?